# Content By Query Web Part Exception

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part

I have a particular situation with CBQWP on a page. Whenever I add a new CBQWP to the page, and click save, an SPWeb not closed exception is raised.

I have nothing on this page, except two CBQWPs. As soon as I add another, it throws this exception, and I don't know how to debug this. The ULS logs are of no help either.

Comment: Any other customisations to the page? Custom masterpage? Custon controls? Does it work on a vanilla (uncustomised) site?

Comment: custom master page with a custom page layout yes. but there is really nothing except cbqwp on the page, and images

Comment: I'm just betting the custom masterpage is loading some script that's interfering with the web parts. Try it on a vanilla, unbranded site.

Comment: I'll fiddle around and see if it is, thanks for the feedback.